# simple subquery in From

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just started to learn sql currently studying about subqueries. 
so 
My table is have just one column named mark with 95,80, 74, 49, 67, 89, 57 in it.

[image]

Here is my sql code

```
 SELECT mark FROM (SELECT mark FROM Music.dbo.MARKS WHERE mark > 80);
```

I am using ms sql server and Azure Data Studio. But it said like this

> **Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near ')'.**

I don't know what is wrong with my code. any advice?

Comment: Welcome to SO. SQL server requires you to provide an alias for all sub-queries, so you need an alias after ). That is why the error says near ')'.

Comment: The solution of your issue is obviously giving an alias name to your sub query as every one mentioned. But for getting more insight about sub query, you can visit some blogs like - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sub-queries.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give your sub-query an alias name

```
 SELECT mark 
 FROM (SELECT mark FROM Music.dbo.MARKS WHERE mark > 80) SubQuery
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT mark FROM (SELECT mark FROM Music.dbo.MARKS WHERE mark > 80)a
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b1b9bf/1)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Marks(Mark int)
INSERT INTO Marks(Mark) VALUES (95),(80),(74),(49),(67),(89),(57)
```

**Query 1**:

```
 SELECT mark FROM (SELECT mark FROM Marks WHERE mark > 80) as q
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b1b9bf/1/0)**:

```
| mark |
|------|
|   95 |
|   89 |
```